# Pytesseract consistently reading a particular number incorrectly

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, ocr, tesseract

I have this image

[image]

I am trying to read the number in the box and it clearly should be the number `1`; however, the code that follows consistently reads it as the number `4`. Seems odd that it would get this wrong as there are many similar instances in the pdf forms I'm working with where it does get it right. Is there anything I can do to correct this particular situation without impeding what is being done correctly?

**The image is just a portion of a fillable pdf form.** I read the pdf and save it as an image. Then tesseract reads the image into a text file.

Here is what the text looks like after it is converted to a `jpg` file

[image]

```
image_counter=1
pages = convert_from_path(filename,  poppler_path= dir_path+r'\poppler-0.68.0\bin') 
for page in pages:
    filename = "page_"+str(image_counter)+".jpg"                  
    # Save the image of the page in system 
    page.save(filename, 'JPEG') 
          
    # Increment the counter to update filename 
    image_counter+=1

# Variable to get count of total number of pages 
filelimit = image_counter-1

# Iterate from 1 to total number of pages 
for i in range(1, filelimit + 1): 
    filename = "page_"+str(i)+".jpg"
    # Recognize the text as string in image using pytesserct 
    text = str(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename), config='--psm 6 --dpi 300 --oem 3'))
    f.write(text) # f is the file I am writing to
```

Answer (score 0):

Psm value 11 with whitelisting digits worked for me:

```
    >>> image = cv2.imread("1.png",0)
    >>> thresh = cv2.threshold(image,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    >>> data = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh,config= '--psm 3 digits')
    >>> data
    ''
    >>> data = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh,config= '--psm 5 digits')
    >>> data
    '-\n .'
    >>> data = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh,config= '--psm 6 digits')
    >>> data
    '11'
    >>> data = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh,config= '--psm 7 digits')
    >>> data
    '11'
    >>> data = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh,config= '--psm 11 digits')
    >>> data
    '.\n\n1' #whitelist here
    >>> data = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh,config= '--psm 12 digits')
    >>> data
    '14'
```

Correct output(with whitelisting digits):

```
    >>> data = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh,config= '--psm 11 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=1234567890')
    >>> data
    '1'
    >>> data = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh,config= '--psm 6 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=1234567890')
    >>> data
    '11'
    >>> data = pytesseract.image_to_string(image,config= '--psm 11 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=1234567890')
    >>> data
    '1'
```

And do not forget to binarize the image before passing for better results.

Comment: Whitelisting didn't seem to help. I assume it's because I provided just a snipit of a much larger image. `--psm11` did seem to help but then elsewhere in the document a number was misread in a way similar to the first. Binarizing the image seemed to make things worse all together.

Comment: Oh, I see. I guess you have images that contain huge texts, in that case whitelisting does not help, sorry. Tesseract does not give 100% accurate results with such large text. Even though you have done a lot of preprocessing, at some or the other place it reads something wrong. Binarization depends upon the image(not just otsu's) and would help in increasing accuracies.

Comment: I appreciate you reaching out. Thanks. These boxes come from a pdf fillable form. I've learned that changing to a smaller font on those seems to be helping.